# How to use UTF-8 in vim on Mac OS X?

Tags: mac, vim, terminal.app, utf-8, locale

I want to edit UTF-8 documents with vim (7.2 installed via MacPorts, big feautre set, iconv support enabled, multi-byte support enabled) on Mac OS X 10.4 within terminal.app.

Terminal.app is configured to use Monaco font (which has good Unicode coverage) and use UTF-8 as the character set encoding.

Keyboard map is set up correctly. I can enter some localized characters like „zażółć” and even quotes around that… (yeah, and an elypsis).

I've done my best to set up the environment:

```
LC_ALL=pl_PL.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE=pl_PL.UTF-8
LANG=pl_PL.UTF-8
export LC_ALL
export LC_CTYPE
export LANG
```

I have no encoding, fileencoding or termencoding set in .vimrc, so that it should default to what's set in the locale.

What else have I missed? I can't enter non-ASCII UTF-8 characters in vim. It is interpreted as single-byte garbage rather than wider UTF-8 characters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out this:

> (Thanks to Peter Vohmann for this Q&A.) In Terminal.app go the the Terminal (main) menu and
>   choose Window Settings. Select Emulation from the popup menu, un-check the item
>   "Escape non-ASCII characters". Then select Display from the popup menu,
>   set Character Set Encoding to Unicode (UTF-8), if desired.
>   Click on "Use settings as Default."

(from [MacVim Site](http://macvim.org/OSX/index.php))

As far as I remember, 10.4 Terminal.app has some troubles, when dealing with UTF-8; checking setting above would, probably, help. As an alternative solution, consider using MacVim or iTerm as terminal application.

Update: as Ben Stiglitz mentioned in comments, 10.4 Terminal is OK, but 10.4 bundled shells are not.

Comment: Terminal 1.5 in 10.4 does fine with UTF-8 if you set your LANG properly. There are some issues with the shells, especially bash and tcsh, that were resolved in Leopard.

Comment: Unselecting escape non-ASCII characters did the trick. I'll upgrade to snow leopard in a week or two anyway. Thanks

Comment: Did the trick for me!
OS X 10.7.2, homebrew console Vim (to get clipboard support).

Comment: Thanks, this problem stumpted me for a while today, thinking why some characters didn't work no matter what encoding I used.

Comment: Links busted ....

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about Vim in the Terminal, but I have no troubles entering Korean characters in [MacVim](http://code.google.com/p/macvim/). This is with no extra setup, just as it came.